# Min/Max across an array of objects

Tags: javascript

It has been done to death pretty much, here on SO and around the 'Net.  However I was wondering if there was a way to leverage the standard min/max functions of:

```
Array.max = function(array) {
    return Math.max.apply(Math, array);
};

Array.min = function(array) {
    return Math.min.apply(Math, array);
};
```

So I can search across an array of objects of say:

```
function Vector(x, y, z) { this.x = x; this.y = y; this.z = z; }
var ArrayVector = [ /* lots of data */ ];
var min_x = ArrayVector.x.min(); // or
var max_y = ArrayVector["y"].max();
```

Currently I have to loop through the array and compare the object values manually and craft each one to the particular need of the loop. A more general purpose way would be nice (if slightly slower).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could make some changes to your `Array.min`and `max` methods to accept a property name, extract that property of each object in the array, with the help of [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/Map), and the max or min value of those extracted values:

```
Array.maxProp = function (array, prop) {
  var values = array.map(function (el) {
    return el[prop];
  });
  return Math.max.apply(Math, values);
};

var max_x = Array.maxProp(ArrayVector, 'x');
```

I just want to mention that the `Array.prototype.map` method will be available on almost all modern browsers, and it is part of the [ECMAScript 5th Edition Specification](http://www.ecmascript.org/docs.php), but Internet Explorer doesn't have it, however you can easily include an implementation like the found on the [Mozilla Developer Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/Map).

Comment: That is quite an elegant solution. I can see it constructs an new temporary array so I will probably have to cache it, or use it sparingly.